# Find Country, City through IP in my code

Tags: database, ip, geo

I have created an Analytics Reporting page with Drupal, and want to find a service, module or anything that gives me City and Country based on the API I have.

Just plain conversion. When I pass IP through (say, a function), it gives me City and Country.

If it's a Drupal Module, great, otherwise a function, or a database which I can put in my site's database and put a search query to find a city, Country through the IP.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [RouteViews](http://www.routeviews.org/) database which has a downloadable mapping between IP, AS, and Country. Unfortunately, it does not have the city information last I checked.

If you have the cash, try: [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/web_services) It's not that expensive.

Comment: Thanks a lot Man! They also have this http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/, is it radically different? I don't mind purchasing that though.

Comment: Sandeep, I installed MAxmind but I don't get how to populate the date in my database. It's a dat file. Any idea?

Comment: Hey Steve, what date are you referring to?

Comment: Steve, you might find this interesting: https://github.com/mrahma01/iplocation   Note, it queries the "whereismyipaddress.com" web server, so it is subject to a rate limit.